# Unhandled rejection Error: Load timeout for modules: template-registry-entry

Tags: javascript, requirejs, aurelia, requirejs-text

We've created a plugin, and its local demo works.

https://github.com/shaunluttin/aurelia-open-id-connect/tree/master/src

Installing the plugin into another project, though, fails with this sequence of two errors, which are complaining about the `open-id-connect-user-block.html` view/view-model component.

> Uncaught TypeError: plugin.load is not a function
>
> Unhandled rejection Error: Load timeout for modules: template-registry-entry!aurelia-open-id-connect/open-id-connect-user-block.html_unnormalized2,template-registry-entry!aurelia-open-id-connect/open-id-connect-user-block.html,text!aurelia-open-id-connect/open-id-connect-user-block.html_unnormalized3,text!aurelia-open-id-connect/open-id-connect-user-block.html
>   http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout

## What we have tried

Add the component as a global resource in our plugin's `configure` function.

```
function configure(config: FrameworkConfiguration, callback: Function) {

    config.globalResources("./open-id-connect-user-block");

}
```

Add the plugin in the consuming application's `configure` function.

```
export function configure(aurelia: Aurelia) {

  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .plugin("aurelia-open-id-connect", (callback) => callback(oidcConfig));

  aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot());
}
```

Add the plugin in the consuming application's `aurelia.json` file.

```
"bundles": [
  {
    "name": "open-id-bundle.js",
    "dependencies": [
      "oidc-client",
      {
        "name": "aurelia-open-id-connect", 
        "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-open-id-connect/dist/amd/es5/open-id-connect",
        "main": "index"
      }
    ]
  },

  // other bundles

]
```

Set the `requirejs/text` plugin to `stub:false`.

```
 "plugins": [
    {
      "name": "text",
      "extensions": [
        ".html",
        ".css"
      ],
      "stub":false 
    }
```

That creates a 404 new error:

> Unhandled rejection Error: src/../node_modules/aurelia-open-id-connect/dist/amd/es5/open-id-connect/open-id-connect-user-block.html HTTP status: 404

## What we have read

We have seen this issue on GitHub: [Installing normal Aurelia plugins, what Im I doing wrong?](https://github.com/aurelia/cli/issues/212)

- 03 Jul 2016, the Aurelia CLI does not support plugins that contain HTML templates.
- 17 Jul, it was supposed to work with version 0.16.1; we're using 0.18.0, and it doesn't work.
- 28 Jul, to dynamically require text requires setting `stub:false` in the `text` plugin at `aurelia.json > build.loader.plugins`.